# Vulnerability scan on an existing image using tag information

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I need to check if an image exists in Gcp container registry before doing any further operation. So far, I was able to find the following API from https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/get-image-vulnerabilities:

```
GET https://containeranalysis.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_ID/occurrences?filter=kind%3D%22DISCOVERY%22%20AND%20resourceUrl%3D%22ENCODED_RESOURCE_URL%22
```

which lists the images matching the criteria. But I don't have the information required in the criteria. Information I have is:
`commit_id, build_id, image_id and tags`.

Is there any other API or any other way which can help me in vulnerability scanning of an image using the information I have?

Comment: I was able to do an existence check for image using:
https://gcr.io/v2/<project>/<image>/manifests/<tag>
But not vulnerability scan.